# General Additive Model problems with case-control data in r

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, case-control-study, mgcv

I am trying to run the following code using R packages `mgcv` and `survival`:

```
model.2 = gam(USE_AVAILABLE ~ strata(CASE_ID) + s(X1) + s(X2),
              family = cox.ph(), 
              method = "REML",
              data = dat,
              weight = event1)
```

Upon completing the model run, an error is generated and states `Error in eigen(hess1, symmetric = TRUE) : 0 x 0 matrix`. Is there any insight as to why this error message gets generated using GAMs in R?

Comment: would be very helpful to have example data with data types included

Answer (score 1):

As a guess, I don't see the use of `strata()` in a `mgcv::gam()` formula as being documented as accepted. `?mgcv::cox.ph` has an example where the conditional logit model which *does* use `strata(stratum)` is fitted using `gam()` with `factor(stratum)` in the formula.

Hence I would try fitting your model as:

```
model.2 = gam(USE_AVAILABLE ~ factor(CASE_ID) + s(X1) + s(X2),
              family = cox.ph(), 
              method = "ML", ## ML fitting only
              data = dat,
              weight = event1)
```